# How to hide expand/collapse icon in vaadin treetable?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, treetable

Good day everyone! I have a treetable below:

[image: treetable]

and I have tried to set the itemcaption to null using this code but it doesn't work:

```
public void uncollapseTable(){
    for (Object itemId: tblFinalGrade.getItemIds()){
        tblFinalGrade.setCollapsed(itemId, false);
        unHideChildren(itemId);
        tblFinalGrade.setItemCaption(itemId, null);
    }
}
public void unHideChildren(Object itemId){
    if(tblFinalGrade.hasChildren(itemId)){
        for(Object id : tblFinalGrade.getChildren(itemId)){
            tblFinalGrade.setCollapsed(id, false);
            unHideChildren(id);
            tblFinalGrade.setItemCaption(id, null);
        }
    }           
}
```

Is it possible to remove/hide the expand/collapse icons without css? If not, how do I hide it using css? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to make the table "uncollapsable" or do you just want to get rid of the icons?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the icons. I have already made it "uncollapsable".

Comment: I guess there's no way to do that without css. You should look at these links: [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html), [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html), [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html) as what you're trying to do heavily sounds theme specific.

Comment: @tk12 Thanks. How do I do it with css? I have read [this](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.treetable.html) but I haven't seen the icon thingy. I tried to look at table as well, but I still can't see the icon thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Kukis for the idea. Displaying nothing will remove the icons and the format itself, so I made it invisible instead. I added:

```
.v-treetable-treespacer{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to my theme and recompiled it. So now it looks like this:

[image: Tree table without icon]

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your styles.scss and recompile theme.

```
.v-treetable-treespacer{
    display: none;
}
```

Its not possible to hide this icon using pure Vaadin.

Comment: it didn't work. I just lost the tree format itself. it became an ordinary table :(  [Here](http://bildr.no/view/ZWxqbG1r) is the screenshot. I still want to maintain the "tree" format, but I don't wanna see the expand/collapse icon because it may confuse the users.